# regex for searching a word in a word

Tags: email, regex, csv

i have a csv file which i need to filter mails marked with the word 'spam'
lines look like this

```
email;text;somestatus;mailserver status response; response message
some@mail.com;mx.mail.com;2;connection reset; try later
thisspamshouldmatch@mail.com;somemx.record.com;3;spam message response; connection reset
thisshouldnotmatch@somedomain.net;spammxrecord.com;5;Deferred: lsjdflsdj; try later
shouldmatchspam@too.de;mx-too.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mx-too.de.;4;Deferred: Connection reset by mx-too.de.
```

lines 3 and 5 should match

the pattern should match if in the first csv part
(the chars until the first ';') contains the word 'spam'
it shouldnt match if the word is within the other columns of the csv

i tried with

```
grep -e "spam[^;]*;\([^;]*;\)\{3\}"
```

anyone knows the solution?
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `grep -e "^[^;]*spam[^;]*;"`

Comment: seems working
thx